# FFMPEG for thumbnail from video distorted when downloaded

Tags: ffmpeg, thumbnails

I am grabbing a thumbnail image from an mp4.

When I use `-c:v mjpeg`, the thumbnail appears fine in the browser, but is completely distorted when I preview it on my Mac. If I use `-c:v jpeg2000` the image looks fine on my Mac, but it does not show in the browser.

Full command:

`ffmpeg -ss 3 -i https://some_site/some_video.mp4 -vf thumbnail,scale=480:480 -q:v 2 -frames:v 1 -f image2 -c:v jpeg2000 -r 1 -vframes 1 tmp/my_thumbnail.jpg`

-vs-

`ffmpeg -ss 3 -i https://some_site/some_video.mp4 -vf thumbnail,scale=480:480 -q:v 2 -frames:v 1 -f image2 -c:v mjpeg -r 1 -vframes 1 tmp/my_thumbnail.jpg`

What encoding do I need to use in order for the generated thumbnail to both be viewable in the browser and also preview-able on Mac?

This is what the distorted image looks like:
[image]

I'm beginning to think this is an macOS issue, but even if it is, I'd like to know if FFMPEG would have a solution for it so that even users with the buggy OS can properly preview the image.

Output:

```
ffmpeg version 4.1.5 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8.3.0 (Alpine 8.3.0)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --enable-avresample --enable-avfilter --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libxvid --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-postproc --enable-pic --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-libxcb --disable-stripping --disable-static --disable-librtmp --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-libopus --disable-debug
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'https://some_site/some_video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isomavc1mp42
    creation_time   : 2020-02-28T16:46:30.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:06.23, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2004 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 480x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], 1951 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-02-28T16:46:29.000000Z
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 48 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-02-28T16:46:29.000000Z
File 'tmp/my_thumbnail.jpg' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> mjpeg (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0x55acb21fbb00] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
Output #0, image2, to 'tmp/my_thumbnail.jpg':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isomavc1mp42
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p(pc), 480x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 1 fps, 1 tbn, 1 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-02-28T16:46:29.000000Z
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 mjpeg
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
[Parsed_thumbnail_0 @ 0x55acb21e35c0] frame id #58 (pts_time=1.933333) selected from a set of 97 images
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=2.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:01.00 bitrate=N/A dup=1 drop=1 speed=2.04x    
video:39kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

Comment: @llogan Updated. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I just missed one "download" in my edit. It just was bc in prod I save the thumbnail to S3 and then download it. Updated again. But, your fix worked! Thank you so much! If you want to add this as the answer, I will mark it as the accepted answer.
And just for future reference, how did you know that? I didn't find that anywhere in ffmpeg docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not like the 4:4:4 subsampling as shown in the log (yuvj444p).

In `ffmpeg` this is named the *pixel format*. The encoder mjpeg supports yuvj420p,  yuvj422p, and yuvj444p as shown with `ffmpeg -h encoder=mjpeg` under *Supported pixel formats*. By default `ffmpeg` will automatically try to choose the least destructive pixel format, but crappy decoders may not support more complicated formats.

You can output a specific pixel format with the [format filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#format) or the legacy `-pix_fmt` output option:

```
ffmpeg -ss 3 -i https://some_site/some_video.mp4 -vf "thumbnail,scale=480:480,format=yuvj420p" -q:v 2 -frames:v 1 tmp/my_thumbnail.jpg
```

4:2:0 (yuvj420p) will be the most widely supported, but try 4:2:2 (yuvj422p) first as it may look slightly better.

Other tools can deal with this too such as the GIMP (File → Export As → Export → Advanced Options → Subsampling).